# classloader and web application and the lib directory of war file

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, classloader

After dig in classloader, a question comes.

suppose we have a library.jar, we could put it in CLASSPATH, it will be loaded by system's CLASSPATH loader.

and also we could put it in lib directory of war file. and it will be loaded by individual web application class loader.

suppose the library.jar has a class with a static member field:

```
static a=1; //member of some class in library.jar
```

if library.jar loaded by CLASSPATH loader, it means this static member will be seem the same by ALL web application. and MAYBE this will interfere!!

so, I think the best way is put the library.jar in lib directory, is it true?

Comment: If the library has such behaviour then it belongs to war.

Answer (score 0):

Put as many jar files into the *lib* directory of the *war* file. That way, you have the best isolation between the web application and no conflicts regarding different versions of the same library.

If you need to share global data between two web application, which is rare, then put the library into the *lib* directory of Tomcat. You probably need to do this for the library used to access the database such as ojdbc6.jar.

Never put additional libraries on the CLASSPATH.